# Creating the Timer which will invoke a method every XXXXms

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, sleep

I would like to create an object which will invoke method called `loadNextImage` every let's say 1000ms. I can do it by creating a new `Thread` which will sleep for 1000 then call this method but I do not know how to do it neat.

Comment: And you can't use a `Timer` or `ScheduledExecutorService` because?

Comment: @BoristheSpider And you draw that conclusion because?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadNextImage();
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will run the submitted `Runnable` every one second.

You create an anonymous `class` that `implements Runnable` and in its `run` method you call your `loadNextImage()` method.

Comment: +1 for suggesting ScheduledExecutorService and not the TimerTask!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `java.util.Timer` class that is designed for that purpose:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29

You just need to implement a subclass of `TimerTask` where your repeated action will be executed.